# connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed

Tags: azure, networking, tcp, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am trying to connect app service and key vault. I am getting the below error message from app service on connecting to key vault. 'connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

The issue is, it is working for some request and connecting to key vault successfully after some time it gives the above error message.

Please let me know what may be the issue the connection is failing after some time.

Comment: Do you allow your app service outbound IP or vnet in the firewall and network of azure key vault?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: after checking the app insights System.Net.Sockets.SocketException is getting from App service while connecting to key vault

Comment: Please provide more information, you can locate the code part according to the log. Update your question, thank you.

Comment: With an error of this nature, I would encourage you to create a support ticket, so engineers can investigate and provide you any other troubleshooting options we may have.